# Add page series to every second row

Tags: excel

I have list of ID extracted from different page numbers. I wanted to add page number to every second row in Excel as shown below:

```
ID Number | Page Number
    1     |     1
    2     |     1
    3     |     2
    4     |     2
    5     |     3
    6     |     3
    7     |     4
    8     |     4
    9     |     5
    10    |     5
```

*Is there any way to do it?*

Comment: what exactly do you want ... a formula that calculates page number from ID (whereby ID is a set of numbers always incrementing by 1)?

Comment: Are the ID numbers always sequential starting at **1**?

Comment: @Jeeped Even if they are not, we can just add an `id` column which is sequential.

Comment: Yes the page number increments by 1 after every two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use in column B1:

```
=TRUNC((ROW()-x)/2)+1
```

while `x` is the row to start with
Or when matching with ID:

```
=TRUNC((A2-1)/2)+1
```

and then auto-fill down (in second case, `A2` is the ID to that page -> order of ID's doesn't matter)

Comment: If you seed the `ROW()` to start, you can put the formula anywhere and fill down. e.g. `=TRUNC((ROW(2:2)/2))`

Comment: No. `=ROW(2:2)` filled down is simply **2, 3, 4,** etc. I use `ROW(1:1)` all the time in the *k* parameter of SMALL or LARGE to get the first, second, third, etc. as the formula is filled down.

Answer (score 0):

If you put values in the first 2 Page number rows then set the 3rd row to be the value of the first row, this forumla can be copied for all remaining rows

```
| |A|
|1|1| 
|2|1|
|3|=A1+1|
|4|=A2+1|
|5|=A3+1|
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. A very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula into cell `B2` and copy down the column:

```
=ROUND(A2/2, 0)
```

where `A2` is a value from the `ID Number` column.

[image]